# How to define an object like 1?

Tags: haskell

In haskell `1 :: Num a => a`.

How could I (if in any way) replicate this behaviour, i.e.
define a typeclass `MyNum`, (probably types, and instances) 
and an object `One` which is of
type `One :: MyNum a => a`?

Comment: `1` is not an object! `1 :: Integer`, `1 :: Int`, `1 :: Double` etc. are all entirely different values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class MyNum a where
  one :: a
```

Now `one :: MyNum a => a`. You can then write

```
instance MyNum Int where
  one = 1
```

and so forth.

Not sure what you're *actually* trying to achieve, or if this is just a toy experiment or something. But I think that answers the question literally asked.

Comment: I was just curious about how to define an object with a typeclass constraint  without using such objects.

Comment: Also, if we use `class MyNum a where fromString :: String -> a` we can write `fromString "1"` and that will have type `MyNum a => a`. This is actually similar to what happens in class `Num`, which has a method `fromInteger :: Integer -> a`, so that `fromInteger (21::Integer)` has the bounded polytype.

Comment: In general, to get something like `c a => a` for some typeclass `c`, that typeclass must have a function with `a` in a positive position.